# Why I am having error like this? I use datatables jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using [for css](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css)

and [for datatables](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js)

Please help me in my problem I want to implement table sorting. Thanks!

I am having error like this.

[image]

Full Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link href="https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

    <script src="https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>"
            });
            $.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
                "sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">


    <div class="span12">
        <table id="example" class="data-results table table-striped table-hover table-bordered tablesorter">

        </table>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js` is an HTML document not a JavaScript file.

Github repositories are not CDNs. You need to check the code out (or follow the download link from the [project homepage](http://www.datatables.net/)) and host it somewhere.

Comment: There is a link in my answer. The file is big because it contains lots of support materials such as documentation, examples, unit tests and graphics.

Comment: what are the unnecessary files so that i will delete it?

Comment: what are the unnecessary files so that i will delete it?

Comment: No idea, I've only glanced at it. Try the documentation.

Comment: I'd suggest you read 'first steps': http://datatables.net/blog/Getting_started_with_DataTables%3A_First_steps . Also, if you don't want to host the files, the Microsoft CDN has them available: http://datatables.net/blog/Microsoft_CDN